# What's the fullname of 'PPI' in malware?

Tags: malware

I want to konw the fullname of PPI .

The meaning of PPI is a single installation fee,

but I don't know its real fullname.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can think that you're asking for is what the acronym PPI stands for.
it's **Pay-Per-Install**

However this could've easily been discerned by yourself by googling PPI.
Here's a [Symantec report on the PPI malware phenomenon](https://www.symantec.com/content/en/us/enterprise/media/security_response/whitepapers/pay_per_install.pdf)